# In c++, how do I create point locations arbitrarily?

Tags: c++, arrays, simulation, point, cartesian

I'm trying to program a simulation. Originally I'd randomly create points like so...

```
for (int c = 0; c < number; c++){  
    for(int d = 0; d < 3; d++){  
        coordinate[c][d] = randomrange(low, high);
    }
}
```

Where randomrange() is an arbitrary range randomizer, number is the amount of created points, and d represents the x,y,z coordinate. It works, however I want to take things further. How would I define a known shape? Say I want 80 points on a circle's circumference, or 500 that form the edges of a cube. I can explain well on paper, but have a problem describing the process as coding. This doesn't pertain to the question, but I end up taking the points to txt file and then use matlab, scatter3 to plot the points. Creating the "shape" points is my issue.

Comment: Do you want it **really** random? Or can you just distribute 83 points randomly over each face of the cube? Also, check out the Standard C++ `<random>`. I think you're not familiar because your `randomrange` looks like a `std::uniform_real_distribution`

Comment: The function there is just an imaginary example. I'm using a C header with randomized functions. It's r1273 or something like that. I don't necessarily need them random. In fact, I'd prefer a uniform allocation of points.  From there if I need some randomness to the shape I'll just add a lesser randomized value to each x, y, z component.

Answer (score 2):

Both a circle and a cube edges set are 1-dimensional sets, so you can represent them as real intervals. For a circle it's straightforward: use an interval (0, 2pi) and transform a random value phi from the interval into a point:

xcentre + R cos(phi), ycentre + R sin(phi)

For a cube you have 12 segments, so use interval (0, 12) and split a random number from the interval into an integer part and a fraction. Then use the integer as an edge number and the fraction as a position inside the edge.

Comment: Or don't bother with the splitting, and use two distributions: A `std::uniform_int_distribution` to pick the edge and a `std::uniform_real_distribution` along the edge.

Comment: Yes, that's simpler than what I wrote. However pseudo-random generators may display some correlations between consecutive results, in which case it is better to use a single result for positioning (unless you *must* use several results, e.g. when positioning in a multi-dimensional space, like a circle or cube's interior).

Comment: I wouldn't worry about that with `<random>`, the included RNG's are strong enough. I wouldn't worry about correlations between bits in a single result either, which is the problem with using a single result. And no, with a multi-dimensional space you don't necessarily need multiple results. If your RNG produces 64 bit results, and you have 32 bit resolution per dimension, then a single result will be sufficient. OTOH, if each dimension uses a 64 bits double, while your RNG produces only 32 bits, then you will need 2 results per dimension. You cannot correlate dimensions and results needed.

Answer (score 0):

Easy variant:
First think of the min/max x/y values (separately; to reduce the faulty values for the step below),   generate some coordinates matching this range,   and then check if it fulfills eg. `a^2+b^2=r^2` (circle)
If not, try again.

Better, but only possible for certain shapes:
Generate a radius between (0-max) and an angle (0-360)
(or just an angle if it should be on the circle border)
and use some math (sin/cos...) to transform it into x and y.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system

Comment: I believe i tried what you're suggesting. I attempted a helix of pi rotation as a sample. Created the x's as a range of evenly displaced values, made the y = square(rad^2-x^2), then stepped z up by some amount.    for (int c = 0; c < sample_size; c++) {
        cord[c][1] = (((c/sample_size)-0.5) * radius);
        cord[c][0] = (sqrt(pow(radius,2)-pow(cord[c][1],2))+ 400000000);
        cord[c][2] = ((c/sample_size) * radius);
    }    The code ran, but did not output my curved line.

Comment: Random radius will make a disc (full circle) not just a circle's edge. Additionaly one should use non-uniform distribution for R to avoid a concentration of generated points around the circle's center.

Comment: @CaptainMorgan That looks too compliated... what do you exactly want to calculate with this code?

Comment: One should take r_of_a_point=R_of_a_circle*sqrt(X) where X is randomly chosen from (0,1) interval with uniform distribution (plus uniform angle distribution between 0 and 2*pi) to obtain a uniform distribution of points over the circle area.

Comment: It is kind of overdone. I'll try the polar approach. I'm thinking a for loop to step up to the intended sample size, and during each step I'll generate a theta from 0 to 2pi. From there ill have this theta assign a value as x=costheta, y=sintheta, z=blah. that should do it.

Comment: For the filled circle case, rejection sampling is a real option. Generate x and y uniformly over `[-R, +R]`, reject if `x*x+y*y > R*R`. This means you'll need to generate on average 4/pi more numbers, which isn't too bad (about 30%). This method works well if (A) you can easily create a uniform distribution over a the whole region and not too much of the surroundings, and (B) have an efficient method to test if a point lies within the intended volume.

Comment: The simulation is of tumor cell detection. Although a randomized space is more realistic, to visually observe detection analysis it's more convenient to have a predefined shape of tumor cells, such as the cube edges. This all in discussion is just the cell establishment, eventually the code creates a similar size set of cells that vary by some small distance. I.E. The randomization and detection is simple, it's creating the cells to a predefined shape that's bothersome.